# TYPO3 uploads to FAL migratrion

Tags: typo3, updates, fal

is there any easy way to migrate TCA or Flexform fields for file uploads from type 'group' (upload directly to uploads folder) to 'inline' (FAL) and keep the already uploaded images?

Answer (score 0):

For 6.2 there is this useful extension doing the job: https://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/conn_falmigration

**BACKUP FIRST!** This extension will override the TCA of those fields and migrate them to FAL. This should **only be a quick fix**. A better solution is to check out the migration logics of that extension and implement them for your own purpose including a real change of the TCA in the desired extensions.